# Querying 11g Oracle database from SQL Server 2012

Tags: oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I have an Oracle database in one server and SQL Server database in another server. I did a count query on the Oracle database locally which returns certain amount of records. However, I was given different record count when I do the same query from the SQL Server.

Below is the Oracle query statement;

```
select count(*) as TOTALDATA
from
(
select b.name,b.prprty,b.result
from thedatabase.ip_smpl a, thedatabase.ip_tst_rslt b
where a.name = b.name
and a.smpl_dt_tm < to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||' 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
and a.smpl_dt_tm > to_date(to_char(sysdate-30,'dd/mm/yyyy')||' 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
and b.result is not null
and b.name not like 'T%')
```

Meanwhile, here is the equivalent SQL Server query statement;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTALDATA 
FROM
(
SELECT b.NAME, b.PRPRTY, b.RESULT 
FROM [LinkedServer]..[thedatabase].[IP_SMPL] a, [LinkedServer]..[thedatabase].[IP_TST_RSLT] b
WHERE a.NAME = b.NAME
AND a.SMPL_DT_TM < CAST(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 23) + ' 00:00' AS DATETIME)
AND a.SMPL_DT_TM > CAST(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE() - 30, 23) + ' 00:00' AS DATETIME)
AND b.RESULT IS NOT NULL
AND b.NAME NOT LIKE 'T%') AS D
```

The former query returns 18263 rows of record while the latter 17849.

Why the different? Perhaps the SQL statement is not literally translated to the same as Oracle statement?

> Note that I get same record count if I ran each query minus two last statements.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but: `to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||' 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')` can be simplified to `trunc(sysdate)`  (and `trunc(sysdate) - 30` likewise). Also: why you name "thedatabase" is actually a schema, not a "database".

Comment: Are you absolutely sure both databases contain absolutely identical data? Most probably they are different somehow

Comment: Side note: I'd recommend using proper `JOIN` syntax on both queries.

Comment: Do you get the same count if you omit only `AND b.NAME NOT LIKE 'T%'`? Perhaps the difference is due to case-sensitivity.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I made the query to the same Oracle schema though one from the server where the schema is located while another one from SQL Server via linked server. Hence it is the same database and not two databases.

Comment: @DanGuzman I still get different count when I omitted `AND b.NAME NOT LIKE 'T%'`. I get same count on both if I omit `AND b.NAME NOT LIKE 'T%'` and also `AND b.RESULT IS NOT NULL`.